# enable local cache on emqx

Tags: mqtt, emq

I see the documentation on https://docs.emqx.io/broker/v3/en/guide.html#emq-x-bridge-cache-configuration and it says that you can enable the cache on file if the network fails because emqx now is not doing this stuff.

When i set, for example the parameter on emqx 3.0.0.0 it fails on start and says in the lof file that is not declared:

```
You've tried to set bridge.xxx.queue.replayq_seg_bytes, but there is no setting with that name.
2020-03-03T19:43:22.777171+03:00 [error] Did you mean one of these?
2020-03-03T19:43:22.962094+03:00 [error] bridge.$name.mqueue_type
2020-03-03T19:43:22.962572+03:00 [error] bridge.$name.clean_start
2020-03-03T19:43:22.962760+03:00 [error] bridge.$name.start_type
2020-03-03T19:43:23.102793+03:00 [error] Error generating configuration in phase transform_datatypes
2020-03-03T19:43:23.103040+03:00 [error] Conf file attempted to set unknown variable: bridge.aps.queue.replayq_seg_bytes
```

You know if its problem of my version of emqx or is possible a problem with the sintax.

Thanks in advance
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

It's sintax error.

```
bridge.xxx.queue.replayq_seg_bytes
```

It's means set the xxx bridge use `queue.replayq_seg_bytes` config.

```
bridge.mqtt.xxx.address = 127.0.0.1:1883
```

Is exists? By the way the EMQ X v4.0.6 is recommended.